# How to make borders in video streams

Tags: league-of-legends

Ive been watching a lot of streams lately, and some streamers have boxes or borders over certain things with logos in them. Does any one know what program they are using??

Comment: Hi, Serion, welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, this isn't really a *gaming* question.  It's more about video editing and modifications.  As such, I'm going to be voting to close it.

Comment: Oh Okay, i thought it was related because i was watching LoL streams haha

Comment: @Serion442 FBueckert's cast a close vote, but as of my writing this, he's the only one. There's a fair number of others who *do* feel that this question is on topic. It's being discussed in [chat] at the moment.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Oh well thank you yea, i was just wondering because i thought it might be kinda cool later in my LoL career if i get better hahah thank you

Answer (score 2):

The program that most League of Legends streamers use is called X-Split. It allows them to add a transparent image file to the stream as an overlay which appears above everything else.

Comment: If this answered your question, then you should hit the check-mark to accept it.